# Wordpress Memory limit Increase issue with .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress

I included below line of code in .htaccess file but still it showing same memory limit (upload file size) on my wp page 
https://cbseneet2019.co.in/neet-2020-result/

```html
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value memory_limit 400M
php_value max_execution_time 180
php_value max_input_time 180
```

please resolve this issue.

Comment: Edit the `wp-config.php` file and insert the following code to increase the PHP memory limit for WordPress. `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );`

Comment: These settings are also set in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

> Hi, check if the file has write permission or not using terminal.
>
> As of now wordpress 5.3 gives the default file limit of 100MB.

If using Wordpress 5.2

> Now let's understand the meaning or use of keywords.

- **upload_max_filesize**

  > This defines the maximum upload limit for files.
- **post_max_size**

  > This defines the maximum upload limit that will be handled in a POST request.
- **memory_limit**

  > This defines how much memory is allocated for PHP. This number should be equal or higher than the upload_max_filesize.

> Now you can modify the .htaccess file (located in the root directory of wotdpress project) and add the below code before the "# END WordPress" in the .htaccess file.

- php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
- php_value post_max_size 70M
- php_value memory_limit 100M
- php_value max_execution_time 300
- php_value max_input_time 300

> Before upload (reflection made using .htaccess with new code)
>   [Before Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaYtT.png) 
>   .
>
> On time of upload [On time of upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9btX.png)